# glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

Tags: r, glm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUk1Z.png)I'm pretty new to data science and R, so please be patient with me :)

What I want is to do a logistic regression model and a confusion matrix afterward, but I get the following warning message:

glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

I have 14 explanatory variables and 1 binary target variable for credit approval (not approved 0, approved 1) [dataset structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zij8L.png)

```
creditApproval <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)
summary(creditApproval)
dim(creditApproval)
str(creditApproval)

creditApproval$class <- as.factor(creditApproval$class)

### Setting seed for reproductability
set.seed(2567)

# Normalizing dataset

approvalNORM <- creditApproval 

for(i in 1:length(colnames(creditApproval))-1) {
  if(class(creditApproval[,i]) == "numeric" || class(creditApproval[,i]) == "integer") 
  { minimum<-min(creditApproval[,i])
    maximum<-max(creditApproval[,i]) 
    approvalNORM[,i] <- as.vector(scale(creditApproval[,i],center=minimum,scale=maximum-minimum)) } } 
summary(approvalNORM) # Normalization

# Logistic Regression 

model <- glm(class ~., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=approvalNORM)
summary(model)
```

Comment: Can you add a sample dataset to reproduce your code?

Comment: The warning is caused by complete separation that is a common problem with logistic regression - especially if you have many predictors and the event is rare. The problem is that you are asking R to estimate probabilities of success for combinations where only one of the two outcomes occur. In these cases the estimated probabilities are either 0 or 1 which reduces to a model with situations with no randomness.

Comment: maybe of interest: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/index.html

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression